# Show that a function is a Borel function

Tags: measure-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions, measurable-functions, borel-sets

Let $u:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R, ~ u(x) = \text{ceil}(x)$ (i.e. round $x$ up to nearest integer).

I need to determine

1. What is the set $\{ u \leq a\}, ~~~ \forall a \in \mathbb R$
2. Show that $u$ is a Borel function i.e. that it is $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)/\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$

**My thoughts so far:**

1. The sets will be all sets that can be written on the form $\{-\infty, \dots ~, \text{floor}(a)-2, ~\text{floor}(a) -1,~ \text{floor}(a)  \}$. As we let $a$ run to $\infty$ we end up with the set of all integers.
2. if I show $\{ u \leq a\}\in \mathscr A$, (where I think $\mathscr A$ should be $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$?) then $u$ should be $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)/\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Is this true, and if so how do I show this mathematically?

Or is it better to show using the pre-image, and if so how? e.g. similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454693/show-that-a-function-fx-is-mathcalb-mathcalb-measureable) (problem is I don't quite understand it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{u\le a\}$ indeed denotes the *preimage* $u^{-1}((-\infty,a])=\{x:u(x) \le a\}$.
This is going to be $(-\infty, \lfloor a\rfloor]$ which is an element of $\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$.

For your second example, $v:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$, so it's rather the single $(-\infty, a]$ rays that generate $\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$, and the '?' is to be filled by $a$. 
The preimage of $(-\infty, a]$ would be a disk with $v'(x)=\lceil x^2 +y^{\bf 2}\rceil$, but it's a *closed set* also for $v$, with boundary $x^2+y^3=\lfloor a\rfloor$.

Comment: So because the preimage is an element of $\mathbb B (\mathcal R)$ we know u is a Borel function?

Comment: That's the definition of Borel function (the preimage of any Borel set is a Borel set).

Comment: That is a good concise clarification. Merci Berci :-) What about cases where we aren't in $\mathcal R$, but $\mathcal R ^ n$ (I have edited the top level question)

Comment: You have to determine the preimages of a generating family (as e.g. $(-\infty, a] $ for $a\in\Bbb R$) are all Borel sets. It's not much harder in your 2d example.

Comment: I have tried to do so, but I have gotten stuck - I have added my thinking, and where I get stuck. Can you help me?

Comment: I have moved the multidimensional question to a new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2942474/show-that-a-function-is-a-borel-function-in-rn