# Show that a function is a Borel function in $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures

How do I determine whether a function is a Borel funtion in multiple dimensions?
(1D example solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2941080/show-that-a-function-is-a-borel-function) - but I can't seem to generalize it.)

**Example**

$$
v:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R, ~~ v(x,y)=\text{ceil}(x^2 + y^3)
$$

($\text{ceil}$ means round up to nearest integer), and we want to show that it is a Borel function ($\mathcal B(\mathbb R^2)/\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$)

I get a little confused once I get into higher dimensions - any help would be appreciated.

**My thoughts**

We want to find the preimage:

$$
v^{-1}((-\infty, a]) 
= \{
(x,y) : v(x,y) \leq a
\}
$$

From there I need to determine the values of that fit into the preimage (i.e. described as two range of values), which I would like to be an expression of $a$ (?).
The set can be described as:

$$
\{x^2 + y^3 < \text{floor}(a) \}
$$

Which can be described as

$$
(-\infty, x], (-\infty,  (-x^2+a)^{1/3}]
$$

This is an element of $\mathbb R^2$, whereby we conclude that $v$ is a Borel function.

Comment: Note that $v = (\lceil \cdot \rceil) \circ f$, where $f(x) = x_1^2+x_2^3$. The inverse images of $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ have a particularly straightforward shape...

Comment: The preimage of ⌈⋅⌉ is straight forward, but I don't know what the inverse is. And is (⌈⋅⌉)∘f the same as ⌈$x^2+y^3$⌉ ?

Comment: The preimage of $(-\infty, \alpha]$ (with tthe ceiling function) is an interval of the form $(-\infty, \beta]$. Now determine if $f^{-1} ((-\infty, \beta])$ is Borel, where $f(x)= x_1^2+x_2^3$.

Comment: The line with $v^{-1}$ makes no sense. You need to take the inverse image of sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @copper.hat That is a very good point - Thank you. It helped me quite a bit, but I am still not sure if what I have is correct. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much measure theory you've done, but what copper.hat is suggesting is to use the fact that a composition of measurable functions is measurable. This reduces the problem to proving
$$ \text{floor} : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$$
and 
$$ f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, \quad f(x, y) = x^2 + y^3 $$
are measurable (where we take the Borel $\sigma$-algebras throughout). $f$ is measurable since it is continuous and $\text{floor}$ is measurable since it is monotonic (you might want to prove this) so we're done.